# Pageref using cref? Multiple pages?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using `\cref` to refer to different figures in the appendix:

```
\cref{figure1,figure2,...}
```

Now I want to create a `\pageref{}` to it, but I don't know how I can achieve this with multiple pages? So that the first and the last page is given?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Doesn't `\cpageref` do the job?

Comment: @Jubobs How to apply this?

Comment: @Jubobs I think that to get only first and last pages of a range it is `\cpagerefrange` which you need to use

Answer (score 9):

Let say you have three figures respectively on pages 1, 2 and 3. The use of the command

```
\cpageref{figure1,figure2,figure3}
```

will yield

> > pages 1, 2 and 3

However the use of the command

```
\cpagerefrange{figure1}{figure3}
```

will yield

> > pages 1 to 3

**NOTE**: These two commands are part of the `cleveref` package.

Comment: Thanks! But why does \pageref{} give me just the number and not the word "page"?

Comment: Because `\pageref{}` is not coming from the `cleveref` package. It is the same thing with the `\ref{}` which gives only some numbers while `\cref{}` adds some prefix.

Comment: Actually, `cleveref` also automatically compresses page references by default. So `\cpageref{figure1,figure2,figure3}` in your example will yield "pages 1 to~3".